# Need help installing windows on linux

Tags: system-installation

I have Linux installed right now and i download windows 10 ISO. I'm not sure how to use the ISO to create a bootable USB to install windows. I looked around online and i see some people saying that you need to install a program that sets up the USB for you but im not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be well on your way if you were to open a console and type in the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install unetbootin
```

Once that's complete, run unetbootin, select the 'Diskimage' option, and point it at your Windows 10 ISO.  From there it should be smooth sailing.

Good luck with Windows 10...it's proven itself to me to be yet another craptastic OS from Microsoft (slow, buggy, clumsy...I've had multiple clients in my computer repair business to rollback Windows 10 installs).

Comment: While this isn't the place to debate Windows, I definitely think 10 is an improvement over 8/8.1.  But, then again, most anything would be.

Comment: Agreed, just pointing it out since the OP said he's pursuing Windows 10.  I hope it's a dual-boot situation that this user is going for and not a full systems wipe and replace job.  The instructions I gave would be useful for preparing any OS ISO image for use.

Comment: i went to http://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html earlier and ran the commands                                                                                                  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unetbootin that is says to install unetbootin after it ran it said some files werent downloaded that they were old or something like that.  and im not sure if it installed correctly.

Comment: i also tried what you said and it said Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
unetbootin is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/dl.google.com_linux_chrome_deb_dists_stable_main_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
and im not sure what to do. Sorry im not very tech smart

Comment: If unetbootin is already the newest version, that means it's already installed.  Just run it.  Type in the command unetbootin.

Comment: Alternatively, Disk Destroyer will work

Comment: For an individual who self-identifies as "not very tech smart", I doubt dd would be very useful.  Better to stick with something with a GUI...